# Generic Method to Load data from DataGridView to different Class List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I want to create a generic method in which I can take out my DataGridView data into my desired Class list:
following is the DataGridView:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BZw7.png)

following is my class:

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string FatherCNIC { get; set; }
    public int FatherQualificationId { get; set; }
    public int FatherJobId { get; set; }
    public string MotherName { get; set; }
    public string MotherCNIC { get; set; }
    public int MotherQualificationId { get; set; }
    public int MotherJobId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string FatherEmail { get; set; }
    public string MotherEmail { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know where to start from this logic but I tried to pass data grid view and class list object as generic object but unable to bind of loop through the properties of class.
I have to use this logic multiple times that's why I am trying to create a generic method.

Comment: It is better to load a DGV from a datatable.  You can use datagridview1.DataSource = dt.  There are many standard methods for creating a DataTable.  Then there is no need to go from a DGV to a class.  The DataTable can be used instead of the class.

Comment: I am manually editing DataGridView to insert bulk records, that why I need to bind my DGV to my class, not my class to DGV.

Comment: Instead of adding rows to DGV you can add rows to the DataTable.  The row number of DGV and DataTable are the same.  You can't create a class dynamically.  So every time you need a new DGV you would have to create a custom class.  To have a generic method my approach will work.  You approach requires a custom class.